# No overload matches delegate but signature is same

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, event-handling

This is my UserControl

```
    using System.Windows;

    namespace MicrosoftDaysFind22S.Controls
    {
public partial class ToggleSwitchWithHelp
{
    public ToggleSwitchWithHelp()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Header
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
        set
        {
            HeaderTextBlock.Text = value;
            SetValue(HeaderProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
        set
        {
            ToggleSwitcher.IsChecked = value;
            SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Header", typeof(string), typeof(ToggleSwitchWithHelp), new PropertyMetadata("Неизвестная настройка"));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "IsChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(ToggleSwitchWithHelp), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    private void ToggleSwitcher_CheckedChange(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ToggleSwitcher.IsChecked != null) IsChecked = (bool) ToggleSwitcher.IsChecked;
    }

    private void ToggleSwitcher_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleSwitcher.IsChecked = IsChecked;
    }

    public delegate void NotifyCallUserHelpPageEventHandler(string settingName);

    public event NotifyCallUserHelpPageEventHandler CallUserHelpPage;

    protected virtual void OnCallUserHelpPage()
    {
        NotifyCallUserHelpPageEventHandler handler = CallUserHelpPage;
        if (handler != null) handler(Header);
    }

    private void HelpButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnCallUserHelpPage();
    }
}
    }
```

event on page:

```
    public void ToggleSwitchWithHelp_OnCallUserHelpPage(string settingName)
    {

    }
```

and exception(characters stored exactly as in VS!!!):

> No overload for 'ToggleSwitchWithHelp_OnCallUserHelpPage' matches delegate 'NotifyCallUserHelpPageEventHandler

Handler and event have the same signature, I'm not understand why I need creat overload and where. And why in exception not closed last '

My control on page:

```
    <controls:ToggleSwitchWithHelp 
                    Header="Использование местонахождения"
                    IsChecked="{Binding IsAllowUseMyGeopositionSetting, Converter={StaticResource SettingsConverter}, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource AppSettings}}" 
                    CallUserHelpPage="ToggleSwitchWithHelp_OnCallUserHelpPage"/>
```

Last investigate show, if add same event from codebehind all work is fine

```
   public SettingsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ToggleSwitchWithHelp.CallUserHelpPage += ToggleSwitchWithHelp_OnCallUserHelpPage;
    }
```

Why it does not work from layout?

Comment: Can you provide all the code that we need, because there is nothing wrong with the event or the method here, they can be hooked up, so there has to be something else going on.

Comment: Please tell me specifically what is lacking